# Convert vanilla js to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem in converting my websites vanilla js to jQuery
I want to convert

```js
const blue = $('#color-blue'),
       red = $('#color-red');

blue.addEventListener('click', () => {
    delete chat.dataset.color;
});
red.addEventListener('click', () => {
    chat.dataset.color = 'red';
});
```

to use with jquery

Comment: Why tho? Remember: [You might not need jquery](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)!

Comment: Also, that is already using jQuery for the selectors!

Comment: thank you for the suggestion but i really dont want a long js file

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour]. "Thanks" comments are discouraged on SO.

Comment: Hint: the jQuery library _is_ a long JS file, and converting this particular code doesn't save you code. You could one-line what you have and move on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is unnecessary to change the event listeners to jQuery, if for some reason you still want this, the below should work for you!

```js
const blue = $('#color-blue'),
    red = $('#color-red');

blue.on('click', () => delete chat.dataset.color);
red.on('click', () => chat.dataset.color = 'red');
```